# Using SSO for a cryptocurrency app

Tags: account-security, sso, third-party, federation

Let us say you have an app where the users will be required to deposit cryptocurrency. Is it safe to let users sign in with third-party authentication? For example "sign in with Google" or "sign in with Facebook"?

If it is not safe, what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically asking if Google or Facebook will ever turn evil and command their IT team to steal your customer's account (i.e. initiate an SSO flow) to steal their money.

That's something, despite unlikely, you don't want to underestimate. The bigger the company offering SSO, the higher the reputation at stake. They don't want to lose their entire business for a bunch of million $ worth.

Let's say that you are relying on a third party platform, rather than hosting your own. While it's absolutely more secure than maintaining your code base (Google has their own IT engineering team always up to date with security), you are still giving the user the option to escrow the keys to their apartment to some other company.

I don't want to discuss about these big companies' trustability, but you may just want to add an MFA handled by your platform, especially for sensitive operations.

E.g. if you login with SSO you can just see your balance, but then you need a TOTP code or a biometric mobile app scan to transfer funds.

Still, I have never seen one very single bank allowing users to log in with SSO.

Some banks, especially in Europe, are considering the option to **sign up** with eIDAS or equivalent national eIDs, but not to use those as **sign in** mechanism, because it is handled by external SSO entities.

That means you could create your account, and skip the paperwork/selfie part of `KYC` (`Know Your Customer`) with the option of an electronic flow. But then the bank will give you your own username, password and OTP token.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will just avoid SSO better safe than sorry.

Comment: Banks are way behind the times, when it comes to modern security and [everything](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/37480/why-dont-banks-give-access-to-all-your-transaction-activity). Most don't implement 2FA with Google Authenticator, and insist on insecure SMS 2FA. Some have reinvented the wheel and built their own clumsy TOTP generator. So I wouldn't say the lack of an SSO option with banks is an indicator of lack of trust.

Comment: @DanDascalescu I could argue that Google Authenticator is not compliant to the MFA principle of PSD2 (Europe), as the token can be **easily** cloned to multiple devices. Google Authenticator can be backed up and restored to multiple device. On enrollment, I always make a copy of the OTP root key to Keepass, so I can survive a phone reset. Something my bank doesn't absolutely want me to do. In fact they use hardware trust zone with their mobile apps.